# Angular mock fails to inject my module dependencies

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I want to test an Angular controller for my application `fooApp`, defined as follow:

```
var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'hmTouchEvents' ]);
...
```

The controller, `MainCtrl` is defined:

```
"use strict";

fooApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, fooService) {
    ...
}
```

So I've tested several ways to create a test, like this one:

```
'use strict';

describe('MainController test', function () {

    var scope;
    var controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
            angular.mock.module('ngRoute', []);
            angular.mock.module('ngAnimate', []);
            angular.mock.module('hmTouchEvents', []);
            angular.module('cwfApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'hmTouchEvents' ]);

            angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
                    $scope: scope
                });
            });
        });

        it('should display a list', function () {
            console.log('-------------- Run Test 1 | ' + scope);
            expect(scope.currentStep).toBe(1);
        });

});
```

and the result:

```
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16-build.64+sha.245de33/$injector/modulerr?p0=undefined&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16-build.64%2Bsha.245de33%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520undefined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A6%3A471%0A%20%20%20%20at%20wb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A18%3A360)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Qa%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A18%3A447)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20nc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A31%3A191)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.d%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A33%3A176)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A254%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A7%3A298)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A9)
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:471
        at d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:32:400
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at r (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:298)
        at e (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:32:9)
        at Object.$b [as injector] (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:98)
        at workFn (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142:52)
        at Object.window.inject.angular.mock.inject [as inject] (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2133:37)
        at null.<anonymous> (d:/dev/foo/test/jasmine/todo.test.js:15:22)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStep' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (d:/dev/foo/test/jasmine/todo.test.js:25:21)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.023 secs / 0.015 secs)
```

I've also tested with `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('cwfApp'));` (instead of the first `beforeEach` in the previous code), but the error is almost the same.

Regarding my karma.conf.js file, I set this list of files:

```
    files: [
        'app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
        'app/bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.min.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-hammer/angular-hammer.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

        'app/js/foo-application.js',
        'app/js/foo-controllers.js',
        'app/js/foo-services.js',
        'app/js/foo-router.js',

        'test/jasmine/*.js'
    ],
```

The injection seems to fail, but I don't really understand what is missing or wrong in my configuration. The stacktrace above does not give a lot of explanations...

Any idea?

I'm using Angular 1.2.8.

Regards

Edit, with the code provided by @Engineer:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('fooApp'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should display a list', function () {
    console.log('-------------- Run Test 1 | ' + scope);
    expect(scope.currentStep).toBe(1);
});
```

The error is almost the same:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16-build.64+sha.245de33/$injector/modulerr?p0=cwfApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16-build.64%2Bsha.245de33%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngAnimate%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16-build.64%252Bsha.245de33%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngAnimate%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(%253Canonymous%253E)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A6%253A471%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A20%253A260%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A21%253A262%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A32%253A69%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A7%253A298)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A32%253A9)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%253A32%253A86%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A6%3A471%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A400%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A7%3A298)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A9)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A86%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A7%3A298)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F5961971009303638e9ad386869316e8c83f67e56%3A32%3A9)
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:471
        at d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:32:400
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at r (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:298)
        at e (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:32:9)
        at Object.$b [as injector] (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:98)
        at workFn (d:/dev/foo/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142:52)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStep' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (d:/dev/foo/test/jasmine/todo.test.js:20:21)
```

I will try to create a fiddle to reproduce my problem...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My problem was in fact due to a little mistake in `karma.conf.js`. Indeed, my application is defined as follow:

```
var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'hmTouchEvents' ]);
```

and my `karma.conf.js` loads the following scripts:

```
files: [
    'app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
    'app/bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.min.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-hammer/angular-hammer.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

    'app/js/foo-application.js',
    'app/js/foo-controllers.js',
    'app/js/foo-services.js',
    'app/js/foo-router.js',

    'test/jasmine/*.js'
], ...
```

but the module `ngAnimate` was not loaded. So I just added that line:

```
    'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
```

and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining fooApp module in the test.

You need to load it with Angular in the test code like this:

```
angular.mock.module('ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'hmTouchEvents', 'fooApp');
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. Sorry, it was just an error of copy / paste, due to many tests made on my code. I've edited the code test and the stack error.

Comment: You lost me... Can you create a fiddle which reproduces the problem? Can you expect(controller).toBeDefined(); ?

Comment: I will try to create such fiddle. I'm wondering if I am not missing something regarding the `fooService`, required by my controller, but not mocked / created...

Comment: The parameters not passed to $controller are injected by Angular regularly, i.e. Angular injects an instance of the real controller

Comment: Finally found the problem (cf. my answer). I forgot to add the `angular-animate` in `karma.conf.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
describe('MainController test', function () {
    var scope;
    var controller;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('fooApp'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    });
    it('should display a list', function () {
        console.log('-------------- Run Test 1 | ' + scope);
        expect(scope.currentStep).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

The thing, you need to understand, is if you declare some module with its dependencies(like `angular.module('fooApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'hmTouchEvents' ])`), when you inject the module(`fooApp`) on your tests, you don't need to inject the dependency modules either.

Comment: Thanks for the information about injection of dependencies. However, trying that code didn't help me (cf. my edited post).