# Unit testing AngularJS factories that have dependencies

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When unit testing an Angular factory (with Karma + Jasmine), how do I inject a stub dependency into the factory under test?

Here's my factory:

```
mod = angular.module('myFactoryMod', []);

mod.factory('myFactory', [
  '$log', 'oneOfMyOtherServices', function($log, svc) {
    return makeSomethingThatDoesSomethingWithTheseDependencies($log, svc);
  }
]);
```

`oneOfMyOtherServices` is needed when instantiating my factory.

Here's my test:

```
it('can get an instance of my factory', function() {
  var oneOfMyOtherServicesStub;

  angular.mock.module('myFactoryMod');

  oneOfMyOtherServicesStub = {
    someVariable: 1
  };

  //****How do I get my stub in my target? ****

  angular.mock.inject(['myFactory', function(target) {

      expect(target).toBeDefined();

    }
  ]);
})
```

N.B. I know that `$controller` allows this for controllers, but I don't see an equivalent for factories.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish something like this that I know of:

1. Use `$provide` and an anonymous module to inject the mock.
2. Inject the service you would like to mock and use jasmine's spying ability to provide mock values.

The second option only works if you know exactly which methods your code under test will be calling on the injected service and you can easily mock them out.  As you seem to be accessing a data property on the service (rather than a method) pursuing the first option might be best.

Using `$provide` would roughly look like this:

```
describe('myFactory', function () {
  // Load your module.
  beforeEach(module('myFactoryMod'));

  // Setup the mock service in an anonymous module.
  beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('oneOfMyOtherServicesStub', {
        someVariable: 1
    });
  }));

  it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(myFactory) {
    expect(myFactory).toBeDefined();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Yeah I think choice 1 is the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to inject the myFactory into all tests. Can it be done in a beforeEach? I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: Thanks for this answer +1. It would be nice to add a code example also for option #2, for completeness.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee Yes, you can. Like this: `var theFactory; beforeEach(inject(function(myFactory) { theFactory = myFactory; } )));` Then use `theFactory` in your test.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee You can also go by the convention and use underscores to reduce the number of variables var theFactory; beforeEach(inject(function(_myFactory_) { myFactory = _myFactory_; } )));

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I understand both options inject the actual service, with the option 1 stubbing one of its method ? Can't we inject a complete mocked service defined in another file ?

Comment: what If i need a combination between mocking one service and injecting a real one?

Comment: How would I spy on a method of this `oneOfMyOtherServicesStub`?

Comment: How can I test this factory method getItemList using Jasmine and karma.

I am getting error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs

(function() {

angular.module('riskCanvasApp').factory('itemsService', itemsService);

itemsService.$inject = [ '$http', '$q','$compile', 'UrlService',
    'accountDetailsMainService', 'sharedService', 'authenticationSvc' ];

function itemsService($http, $q, $compile, urlService, accountDetailsMainService,
                      sharedService, authenticationSvc) {

Answer (score 12):

The comment by @bentsai is actually very helpful for testing services; for completeness I am adding an example.

Here is a test for `jasmine` which does approximately what you're looking for. Note: this requires you to have `angular-mocks` included (this is what provides functions like `module` and `inject`).

```
describe('app: myApp', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  var $controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));
  // Factory of interest is called MyFactory
  describe('factory: MyFactory', function() {
    var factory = null;
    beforeEach(inject(function(MyFactory) {
      factory = MyFactory;
    }))
    it('Should define methods', function() {
      expect(factory.beAwesome).toBeDefined()
      expect(factory.beAwesome).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function))
    });
  });
});
```

This is a stub for what the module and associated factory definition could look like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('MyFactory', function() {
  var factory = {};
  factory.beAwesome = function() {
    return 'Awesome!';
  }
  return factory;
});
```

In this case, it is clear the use of `inject()` allows you to pull in dependencies, just as you would expect in your normal angular application - and as such you can build up requirements to support testing things which rely on them.

Comment: You have missed the part where you inject a stub dependency to MyFactory in testing.

Comment: where's the second dependency?