# Injecting custom factory in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I tried to inject a factory to my controller in jasmine test like in
[Unit testing AngularJS factories that have dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565531/angularjs-unit-testing-a-factory-that-has-dependencies)

When I $provide a factory in the test, I would expect the controller to use the provided factory. But the console.log still prints 'real value'. I don't get it.

```
var app = angular.module('mod', []);

app.factory('factoryA', [
    function () {
        return "real value";
    }
]);

app.controller('myController', ['factoryA',
    function (factoryA) {
        console.log(factoryA);
    }
]);


describe("test", function() {
    var $scope, $controller, $httpBackend;
    var app;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.factory('factoryA', function () { return "fake value"; });
        });
        app = module("mod");

        inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, $rootScope) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_;
        });

    });

    it("works", function() {
        $controller("myController", { '$scope': $scope });
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, any luck with the answer below?

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you. How did you know that the module must be loaded first. You see, it worked but I still don't know why. Where did you learn the correct meaning of the framework elements and reasons behind why and how are they mocked in jasmine? Like why to first load module then provide and not the other way. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, The thing is if you load module first (2nd approach) and then override later or overriding the service in the module itself (1st approach) makes sure that injector get the fake version of factory. If you override without module specs and then load your module later (as you are doing) your fake factory will be overridden by the actual one. Key here is you are accesing `$provide` from which module and when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to get the `$provide`r from the module `mod` so pass module name as first argument so that it overrides the `factoryA` definition that was created originally. Or load the module - `module("mod")` - before setting up mock.

```
   module('mod', function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('factoryA', function () { return "fake value"; });
    });
```

Another way it to create mocks and pass it to the controller creation.

```
describe("test", function() {
    var $scope, $controller, $httpBackend;
    var app, factoryA;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(mod);

        inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, $rootScope) {
            //...Your code
            //Mock factory
            factoryA = jasmine.createSpy('factoryA');
            factoryA.and.returnValue("fake value");
        });

    });

    it("works", function() {
        //Pass the mock factory
        $controller("myController", { '$scope': $scope, factoryA:factoryA });
    });

});
```