# How do I test this simple Angular JS service with Jasmine? I'm facing an unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, assertions

I First I instantiate my app.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
```

Then I have a controller.

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, temperaturesService) {..}
```

Then, I have a service with a method `getMedian()` inside it.

```
  app.service('temperaturesService', function(){
  this.getMedian = function(temps) {
    temps.sort();
    if(temps.length===0) {
       return 0; 
    }else if(temps.length%2===0) {
      return (temps[temps.length / 2 ] + temps[(temps.length/2) - 1]) / 2;
    }else {
      return temps[Math.floor(temps.length/2)];
    }
  }
```

I'm not using any factories to instantiate my service. I'm directly using the service in my controller and getting the desired result. Now, I want to test my service `temperaturesService` . I basically want to see if `getMedian` returns the right values for different inputs.

This is my spec-file.

```
describe('Test suite for temperature monitor app', function(){
  it('Checks if medians are calculated correctly', function(){
      var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
      var $injector = angular.injector(['myapp']);
      var tempService = $injector.get('temperaturesService');
      expect( tempService.getMedian([1,2,3]) ).toEqual(2);
  });

});
```

I picked up this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013772/how-do-i-test-an-angularjs-service-with-jasmine) but the test runner says `unknown provider temperaturesServiceProvider`. Why? What else do I need to do? What are some basic steps one needs to take, to test an angular JS service?

Comment: Have you referred to any tutorial or online material

Comment: Yes, but most examples I saw invoked services through factories and tested those factories. I want to learn from ground up.

Comment: go through this link..will get to know the basics..Its better to start from scratch:-http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine--net-21229

Comment: I know jasmine. I'm trying to get my angular service talk to jasmine so the methods inside it can be tested.

Comment: This line: "var app = angular.module('myapp', []);" initiates a new module with no dependencies. This will overwrite any existing module with the name 'myApp'. I don't think you have grasped the concept about jasmine testing and i suggest you start from scratch with a tutorial.