# Unit test a service : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine, angularjs-service

I have few questions with to write a proper unit test for a service using `jasmine` as framework and `karma` as test runner.

here is what i implemented in **example-service.js**:

```
export default class ExampleService {
constructor($resource, $http, $urlMatcherFactory) {
'ngInject';

this.$resource = $resource;
this.$http = $http;
this.$urlMatcherFactory = $urlMatcherFactory;
}

exampleMethodOne() {
//some code lines
}

exampleMethodTwo() {
//some code lines 
}

}
ExampleService.selector = 'myExampleService';
```

Here what i wrote in my test **example-service.test.js**

```
        let myExampleService, $httpBackend, $urlMatcherFactory;

          beforeEach(() => {
            angular
              .module('exampleApp', ['ngResource'])
              .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
            angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
          });

          beforeEach(inject((_myExampleService_, _$httpBackend_, 
_$urlMatcherFactory_) => {
            myExampleService = _myExampleService_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $urlMatcherFactory = _$urlMatcherFactory_;
          }));
```

i have imported the `angular-mocks.js`, `angular-resource.js` and `example-service.js`

when i try this scenario the console will throw a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $urlMatcherFactoryProvider <- $urlMatcherFactory <- myExampleService` error.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: Angularjs or Angular?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Clearly AngularJS in ES6

Comment: @RameshRajendran you are right angularJS 1.6

Comment: @JohnSingh I think this post should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013772/how-do-i-test-an-angularjs-service-with-jasmine