# AngularJS unit test for service : $urlMatcherFactory throws unknown error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-service

I have few questions with to write a proper unit test for a service using `jasmine` as framework and `karma` as test runner.

here is what i implemented in **example-service.js**:

```
export default class ExampleService {
constructor($resource, $http, $urlMatcherFactory) {
'ngInject';

this.$resource = $resource;
this.$http = $http;
this.$urlMatcherFactory = $urlMatcherFactory;
}

exampleMethodOne() {
//some code lines
}

exampleMethodTwo() {
//some code lines 
}

}
ExampleService.selector = 'myExampleService';
```

Here what i wrote in my test **example-service.test.js**

```
        let myExampleService, $httpBackend, $urlMatcherFactory;

          beforeEach(() => {
            angular
              .module('exampleApp', ['ngResource'])
              .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
            angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
          });

          beforeEach(inject((_myExampleService_, _$httpBackend_, 
_$urlMatcherFactory_) => {
            myExampleService = _myExampleService_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $urlMatcherFactory = _$urlMatcherFactory_;
          }));
```

i have imported the `angular-mocks.js`, `angular-resource.js` and `example-service.js`

when i try this scenario the console will throw a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $urlMatcherFactoryProvider <- $urlMatcherFactory <- myExampleService` error.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you add the uirouter  which contains the $urlMatchFactory to your files array inside Karma?    angular-ui-router.min.js would likely be the file name.

Comment: Why duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624650/unit-test-a-service-angularjs  word for word?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `$urlMatcherFactory` refers to [UI router service](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/url.urlmatcherfactory.html), and UI Router wasn't loaded.

It's not recommended to use real router in unit tests because it provides extra moving parts and breaks isolation between units. As a rule of thumb, every unit but a tested one should be mocked.

`$urlMatcherFactory` stub methods have to be configured to return expected values. Since they are used during `ExampleService` construction, they should be configured prior to service instantiation:

```
  let removeAllUrlMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    removeAllUrlMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('removeAllUrl', ['format']);
    $urlMatcherFactory = jasmine.createSpyObj('urlMatcherFactory', ['compile']);
    $urlMatcherFactory.compile.and.returnValue(removeAllUrlMock);

    angular
      .module('exampleApp', ['ngResource'])
      .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
    angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
    angular.mock.module({ $urlMatcherFactory });
  });
```

This can be tested with:

```
expect($urlMatcherFactory.compile).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
expect($urlMatcherFactory.compile).toHaveBeenCalledWith('../api/v1/user/{Id}/remove/all');
expect(myExampleService.removeAllUrl).toBe(removeAllUrlMock);
```

Then specific `removeAllUrl` calls can be mocked and tested when used:

```
removeAllUrlMock.format.and.returnValue('../api/v1/user/foo/remove/all');
myExampleService.removeProduct('foo');
expect(removeAllUrlMock.format).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
expect($urlMatcherFactory.compile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({ id: 'foo' })
);
```

Since `$urlMatcherFactory` is utility service that doesn't provide much moving parts and supposed to be predictable, it can alternatively be imported and used directly, without UI router module:

```
import { UrlMatcherFactory } from '@uirouter/angularjs';

...

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular
      .module('exampleApp', ['ngResource'])
      .service(ExampleService.selector, ExampleService);
    angular.mock.module('exampleApp');
    angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
      $provide.service('$urlMatcherFactory', UrlMatcherFactory });
    });
  });
```

Then it's just has to be spied:

```
spyOn(myExampleService, 'removeAllUrl').and.callThrough();
myExampleService.removeProduct('foo');
expect(removeAllUrlMock.format).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
expect($urlMatcherFactory.compile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({ id: 'foo' })
);
```

Comment: think about the below scenario and how could it should need to call? because it's getting undefined `  removeProduct(id) {
    return this.$http({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: this.removeAllUrl.format({
        id: id
      })
    });
  }`

Comment: What is removeAllUrl? The question doesn't contain the code you're testing.

Comment: this.removeAllUrl = this.$urlMatcherFactory.compile('../api/v1/user/{Id}/remove/all'); it's initialize in the constructor

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope the description is clear enough.