# Chimp running 0 out of 1 specs (unit test) for angular-meteor app

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine

So I am building an app using angular-meteor. (Angular version 1.3.1, Meteor 1.2.1). I am trying to write unit tests using the chimp framework.

I have the following code at app/tests/features/login_spec.js

```
describe('LoginController', function() {

    console.log("1");
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    console.log("2");


    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));
    console.log("3");


    describe('$scope.login', function() {
        it('sets loggedIn to true if logs in @watch', function() {
            console.log("4");
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope});
            $scope.email = 'user';
            $scope.password = 'password';
            expect($scope.loggedIn($scope.email, $scope.password).toEqual(true));

         });
    });
});
```

But when I run  chimp  --jasmine --watch I get the following output:

```
[chimp] Running...
1
Started



Ran 0 of 1 spec
0 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.003 seconds
```

I don't know why the test isn't running. Any ideas?

I'm following the following tutorials:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/guide/unit-testing

https://chimp.readme.io/docs/getting-started-jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Check the [default Chimp configuration file](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/blob/master/src/bin/default.js): it looks like Jasmine will only load filenames containing `support` (along with your `_spec`s of course). So presumably it doesn't know about Angular unless you configure it to?

Have a look at [the accepted answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939930/1256328). The function `module` in your spec is defined in `angular-mocks`, which you'll need to load along with your app code.

Alternatively, if you're not deeply invested in Chimp, it may be worth considering switching to Jasmine + Karma, which targets Angular natively and as such does most of this plumbing for you.